# See ALL network fileservers

Tags: networking, powershell

There are multiple fileservers on a network and I have access to all of them, but I don't know the domains for all of them.
I would like a (powershell) command or a piece of software that can give me the domains for all of them.
They don't show up in the network tab but I *can* access **two** of them using the their domain names (they look like \[NAME]1\ and \[NAME]2).
I have already tried `net view` `get-psdrives` `get-smbshare` and `get-smbmapping`.

Answer (score 0):

There is no central list of fileservers, neither in workgroup mode nor in Active Directory domain mode. (Fileservers may *voluntarily* have specific shares published in the central AD directory, but that's not the default.)

You would need to get a complete list of all servers on the domain (e.g. `Get-AdComputer` or similar, filtering out desktops by OU) and test each whether it accepts SMB connections (e.g. using `% {}` aka `ForEach-Object {}`, combined with `Test-Path \\$_\something`).

Comment: Do you know of any software or script that can automate this task?